# css div image before parent div background

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to make a image show before it's div background?
here my code:

```
<li class="contest55">
    <div class="view-image-fid"></div>
</li>
```

and in my css i have:

```
#latest_ideas .contest55{
    background-image: url('images/image.png');
    background-size: Auto 185px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
```

I need the background start immediately under the div view-image-fid that has width 250px

tips or idea on how to do it?

Comment: What styles you have for <div class="view-image-fid"></div>?

Comment: Do you mean you want the background image to show through? If so, then apply `background-color:transparent` to `.view-image-fid`

Comment: you can try using `background-position` however it may require us to know about the size (absolute or relative) of your `div`.

Comment: the div only show an image that has width 250px

Comment: @carl1304IT the `height` is important here while the `width` does not matter.

Comment: it scale an image based on the 250px width.. 
ps. i can't put the div out of the <li>, i'm working on a drupal website and trying to customize it

Comment: div view-image-fid that has width 250px has it a height or an image inside <img> element. Always try to illustrate it as a whole otherwise we are guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved using jquery

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".views-image-fid").each(function()
            {
            if ($(this).find(".views-image-fid").length == 1)
            {
            $(this).parent().css("background-position","0 190px");
            }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your CSS as such:

```
.contest55 {
    background-image: url('images/image.png');    
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: Orange;
    height:600px;
    width:300px;;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid Black;
    }
```

The height and width will have to be adjusted so that they 'span' the length of the background image. You can change these values based on the size of your images.

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/s25sm/1/

I have added the border in the fiddle to make the boundaries clearly visible. You can remove them to get the effect you are looking for!!!

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/GqRGV/4/

By using the :after pseudo selector the background image will begin after the image.

```
 li {
     list-style: none;
 }
 .view-image-fid img {
   width: 250px;
   height: auto;
 }
 .view-image-fid:after {
  content:'';
  background-image: url('http://snag.gy/l4EaW.jpg');
  background-size: auto 185px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width: 250px;
  height: 185px;
  display:block;
 }
```